# Get substring before first non-letter

Tags: php, string, text-extraction

How can I get a portion of the string from the beginning until the first non-alphabetic character?

Example strings:

- `Hello World`
- `Hello&World`
- `Hello5World`

I'd like to get "Hello" from each of the above input strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the preg_split feature.

```
$str = 'Hello&World';
$words = preg_split('/[^\w]/',$str);

echo $words[0];
```

You can access Hello by $words[0], and World by $words[1]

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect: https://3v4l.org/Dk9oQ

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) for this:

```
if (preg_match('/^([\w]+)/i', $string, $match)) {
    echo "The matched word is {$match[1]}.";
}
```

Change `[\w]+` to `[a-z]+` if you do *not* want to match the `5` or any numeric characters.

Comment: The subgroup, `/i` flag and brackets can all be safely dropped.

Comment: There is no benefit in writing `\w` inside of a character class.  This answer is provably incorrect. https://3v4l.org/TG0l6

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first part, use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]+/i', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ri4ySi)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). Split string by a regular expression

Comment: This manually link-only answer should have been a comment under the question ...if anything.  Frankly, it is not the best tool for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_split to get first part of alpha.

```
$array = preg_split('/[^[:alpha:]]+/', 'Hello5World');
echo $array[0];
```

Comment: It is unnecessary work to generate an array if only the first substring is desired.

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` can be used to extract the leading letters from the string.  If the string does not begin with letters, then the output will be a `null` value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KUCGs))

```
$string = 'Hello5World';
sscanf($string, '%[A-Za-z]', $firstWord);
echo $firstWord;
```

Alternatively, `preg_replace()` can be used to truncate the string from the first occurrence of a non-letter.  This is immediately accessible without declaring a new variable as done in the above snippet. If the string does not begin with letters, then the output will be a zero-length string value (empty string).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rHIt5))

```
$string = 'Hello5World';
echo preg_replace('/[^a-z].*/i', '', $string);
```